# Seeking help on compiling big projects

Tags: build-process, compilation

Recently I've had to work with big, existing projects to get them to compile. So far, it's been a pain in the butt to download all of the necessary libraries and configure the environment correctly.

If I had a checklist that I could hand to project leads, listing: "here's what I need to run your project," that'd save me time and effort.

Does anyone have any checklists, advice or readings on how to simplify compilation of big projects?

thanks

Comment: Telling us what language, build environment, compiler and IDE you're using would probably help as any checklist is going to vary a bit depending on that. Although that list would actually form the bulk of a *very generalised* checklist! =)

Comment: are you building open-source packages, or company-internal source releases? if the package is poorly documented, you might just have to get a dev on the phone.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if the first was true :-D. It's the second one, Dustin. The reason I need to compile code is because I need to do static analysis. Basically the software I'm using needs to listen to the compilation of a big project, then it generates errors I need to investigate. Maybe it's easier to install the static analysis software on the big project in its home environment, where it can easily be compiled?

Answer (score 1):

Use build scripts. Compiling a large project shouldn't be any more difficult than compiling a small project. A single command should be all that is required.

without knowing what language you're targeting, I can't be more specific.

Comment: I can't specify the language since it varies. However, those build scripts don't always work... (my experience)

thanks, Jamie

Answer (score 0):

almost all nix source distributions come with a README file which should list the dependencies.

Comment: with 100+ libraries, it's lengthy to install (and sometimes even find) the libraries. Plus, I'm guessing that it's not always safe to google for libraries, spyware can get easily planted in them (guess)